# Android gradle file for string constants generates wrong declaration

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set BASE_URL for my services in my gradle script for different build types. When I'm trying to synchronize the script, it generates wrong String value.

My script

```
buildTypes {
    //... other build types
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField "String", "MHT_BASE_URL", "www.my-url.com"
    }
}
```

It generates the following BuildConfig

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.myapp.app_dev";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "dev";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 6;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "0.5.1";
    // Fields from build type: debug
    public static final String BASE_URL = www.my-url.com;
}
```

But it should generate this string (**with quotation marks!**)

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "www.my-url.com";
```

I have a workaround for that but I'm searching for a right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the quotation marks in your Gradle script:

```
buildConfigField "String", "MHT_BASE_URL", '"www.my-url.com"'
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it with only one pair of quotes?

Comment: @inshador: Not that I am aware of. The build tools pretty much just slap what you have in `build.gradle` into the generated code. They aren't examining the data type and massaging your values to match. OTOH, you can actually have fairly complicated `buildConfigField` values as a result (e.g., call a static method, set a value of an enum).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
 buildConfigField "String", "MHT_BASE_URL",  "\"www.my-url.com\""
```

or check the @CommonsWare answer with the single quote.

Comment: I did exactly this to make it work but I don't like this solution. I actually prefer to not use escaped quotes (single or double) inside the enclosing quotes. It just doesn't seem right. Not sure if it is possible.